# How to create an iOS Nested Scrollview similar to the app store details page?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I'm currently trying to work out how to create a screen in my application similar to the Apple App Store details page where you can vertically scroll the view to read the description and then at the bottom there is a horizontal scroller to view images.

Is this a nested set-up or is it two separate scrollviews with the 2nd attached to the end of the 1st one.

Any pointers would be great.

Thanks Aaron

Comment: It's a scroll view within a scroll view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm looking for any advice on how to implement this.

Comment: It's really not complicated--stick a scroll view inside another scroll view.  iOS will automatically take care of everything else.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, your right I actually made it more difficult than it is, this afternoon I did as you mentioned and it works like a dream and also so simple. Thanks again I can't seem to mark your post as the answer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is stick a scroll view inside another scroll view.  iOS will automatically take care of the rest.